# Uploading multiple file upload using PUT request

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files in CHUNKS using PUT request using Jquery to PHP server.
I have created code where I am able to Upload the chunk file.
But something weird is happenening when I try to read it using "php://input"

```
<?php
  $headerArray=getallheaders();
  $filename="d/".$headerArray["filename"];
  $length=$headerArray["Content-Length"];
  /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
  echo "filename".$filename;
  echo "Chunksize Uploaded:".$length;

  $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

  /* Open a file for writing */
  $fp = fopen($filename, "a");

  while ($data = fread($putdata, $length))
    fwrite($fp, $data);

  /* Close the streams */
  fclose($fp);
  fclose($putdata);

  echo "FileSize After write : ".filesize($filename);
?>
```

Here I am able to successfully upload the file in chunks when I am sending each chunk one by one and waiting for code to write that chunk to file.

But when I do the concurrent uploads(Do not wait for the first chunk to be written in the file ) .. data in the "php://input" seems got overwritten by the next request.

I have doble checked the javascript. So the problem is at php end "how should i read the CHUNKS?".

I have gone through the follwing link and several other links:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Can somebody help me to understand how php://input works when it recives multiple request at the same time .. does data gets overwritten or the data gets QUEUED in STDIN?

Comment: Hello Kunal... This sounds really weird to me. Regulary STDIN should not being shared across multiple requests (as this would lead to total confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Before you write, use fseek to make sure you are writing to the end of the file.

Comment: As you can see i have used append mode for writing the fileso this will atomatically seeks for end of file and then it will write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending multiple Uploads as Blob-Parts in JS-Objects. That needs a simple serialize-Algorithm on server, example for Perl:

```
sub init{
    my $self = shift;
    # AJAX Response
    if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'PUT'){
        # Objekte wiederherstellen aus STDIN
        binmode STDIN;
        my $eav = EAVHandle->handle2eav(*STDIN);
        # $eav ermöglicht den wahlfreien Zugriff auf die Einzelteile

        # für die DEMO schicken wir die Objekte wieder zurück
        $self->{CONTENT} = EAVHandle->eav2str($eav);
        $self->header("Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream");
    }
}
```